# receiving of warning that not all control paths return a value

Tags: c++, class, compiler-warnings

I have just finished writing my first mini-project in object-orinted (cpp). It seems that the program is running well, but when I compile it I recieve the following warning:
**: warning C4715: 'Collection::getCircleAt' : not all control paths return a value**. 
I cant understand what is the reason for this warning.

I would like to add some words about my program: 
The program inputs a collection of circles in the integers xy plane, and checks which circle includes a given point in the plane. For that task, I used classes.
The class 'Point' represents a point by its coordinates.
The class 'Circle' represents a colorized circle in the plane. That class contains a variable of type "Point" which represents its center of circle, and a radius. That class also contains a variable named "color", (represented by integers 0 or 2, when 0 means that a circle does not include the point given, and 2 means the contrary), and a function that check if the given point is included in a certain circle.
Finally, we had the class 'Collection', which represents a collection of circles.
The variable "count" is the number of circles, and the variable "circles" is an array of pointers to circles in the collection. **This class contains the function getCircleAt that returns the circle which includes the point. That's the function which makes the warning shown above.**

Heres is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "point.h"
#include "circle.h"
#include "collection.h"

int main()
{
Collection g(4, 3, 2, 0);
cout << "-- before setColor(2) --" << endl;
g.print();
Point p(5, 1);
g.getCircleAt(p).setColor(2);
cout << "-- after setColor(2) --" << endl;
g.print();
return 0;
}

#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point
{
public:
Point(int x, int y);
int getX() const;
int getY() const;
void setX(int x);
void setY(int y);
void print() const;
private:
int x, y;
};

#endif

#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H
#include "point.h"

class Circle
{
public:
Circle(int x, int y, int r, int color);
int getColor() const;
void setColor(int color);
bool contains(const Point &p) const;
void print() const;
private:
const Point center;
int radius, color;
};

#endif

#ifndef COLLECTION_H
#define COLLECTION_H
#include "circle.h"

class Collection
{
public:
Collection(int radius, int width, int height, int color);
~Collection();
Circle& getCircleAt(const Point &p);
void print() const;
private:
int count;
Circle **circles;
};

#endif

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "point.h"

Point::Point(int x,int y )
{
 setX(x);
 setY(y);
}

void Point::setX(int x)
{
    this->x=x;
}

void Point::setY(int y)
{
    this->y=y;
}

int Point::getX() const 
{
    return x;
} 

int Point::getY() const 
{
    return y;
}

void Point::print() const
{
        cout <<"x="<< this->x <<"  "<<"y" << this->y ;
        cout <<"  ";

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "circle.h"

Circle::Circle(int x=0,int y=0,int r=0,int color=0):center(x, y),radius(r),color(color)
{  

}

int Circle::getColor() const
{
    return color;
}

void Circle::setColor(int color)
{
    this->color=color;
}

bool Circle::contains(const Point &p) const
{
    int distX, distY;

    distX=p.getX()-center.getX();
    distY=p.getY()-center.getY();

    if ((distX*distX + distY*distY) > (radius*radius))
        return false;
    return true;
}

void Circle::print() const
{  
    cout<<endl<<"the center of the circle is ("<<center.getX()<<" ,"<<center.getY()<<")"<<" radius "<<radius<<" color "<<color<<endl;  
}


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "collection.h"

Collection::Collection(int radius, int width, int height, int color)   
{
  int i ,j; 

  count=height*width;
  circles=new Circle* [count];

  for(i=0;i<height;i++)
   for(j=0;j<width;j++)
       circles[j+(i*width)]=new Circle (j*2*radius,i*2*radius,radius,color);

}

Collection::~Collection()
{
    delete []circles; 
}

Circle& Collection::getCircleAt(const Point &p)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)     
        if(circles[i]->contains(p) ) 
          return *(circles)[i];
}

void Collection::print() const 
{
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
       circles[i]->print();

}
```

**The expected output is:**

```
-- before setColor(2) --
Circle center=(0,0) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(8,0) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(16,0) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(0,8) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(8,8) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(16,8) radius=4 color=0
-- after setColor(2) --
Circle center=(0,0) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(8,0) radius=4 color=2
Circle center=(16,0) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(0,8) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(8,8) radius=4 color=0
Circle center=(16,8) radius=4 color=0
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. Anyways, `Collection::getCircleAt` has its return statement in an `if`, and the compiler is warning about that. It is undefined behaviour if none of the circles contains the point.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. `getCircleAt` only returns if a condition is met. If the condition is not met, there is no return.

Comment: @Hollyol `NULL` is not a `Circle&`

Comment: White space is free.

Comment: @passer-by no but it still compile right ? and it ensure you will not work on a broken `Circle` after execution

Comment: Prefer using containers or smart pointers rather than manual memory management with `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Who cares if it compiles? Does it make sense to do it? Plus: https://ideone.com/lxjrKz

Comment: Probably a good case for a thrown exception.

Comment: How would you fix the function getCircleAt ?

Comment: I have edited my post, added an output.

Comment: @NOA_ROTH: if there is a possibility that you won't return anything, then you will want to consider an [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)-esque object.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
Circle& Collection::getCircleAt(const Point &p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (circles[i]->contains(p))
          return *(circles)[i];
}
```

when none of the circles contains `p`, no return statement is executed. That means the return value of the function is undefined when that happens.

There's several ways to fix this. The simplest one is to return a pointer instead of a reference, and return `nullptr` when no circle was found:

```
Circle* Collection::getCircleAt(const Point &p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)     
        if (circles[i]->contains(p)) 
          return circles[i];
    return nullptr;
}
```

Another solution that is being suggested here, is to throw an exception. However, I do not recommend this, because exceptions are for **exceptional** cases. There's nothing exceptional about `getCircleAt()` not finding a circle at some given position. It's something normal. It's not an error.

A better solution (in my opinion) is to change the API completely and instead return the index of the circle, not the circle itself. When no circle was found, return -1:

```
int Collection::getIndexAt(const Point &p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)     
        if (circles[i]->contains(p)) 
          return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Then add an `operator []` overload to get access to the circles by their index:

```
class Collection
{
public:
    // ...
    Circle& operator [](size_t index)
    {
        return *circles[i];
    }
};
```

The caller of the function would then need to check if the circle was found:

```
auto index = g.getIndexAt(p);
if (index >= 0) {
    g[index].setColor(2);
    cout << "-- after setColor(2) --" << endl;
    g.print();
} else {
    cout << "-- circle not found at position --" << endl;
}
```

As a side note, your `Collection` destructor is not correct. You are not freeing the circles you allocated. You're only freeing the dynamic array. You need:

```
Collection::~Collection()
{
    // Free each circle.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        delete circles[i];
    // Free the array.
    delete[] circles;
}
```

Another (unrelated) issue in your code, is that you are providing default argument values for your `Circle::Circle()` constructor in the implementation of the constructor, not in its declaration. You should change that. Default arguments should be specified in the declaration. So do this instead:

```
class Circle {
public:
    Circle(int x = 0, int y = 0, int r = 0, int color = 0);
```

And remove the default argument values from the implementation:

```
Circle::Circle(int x, int y, int r, int color)
```

Furthermore, unless this was an exercise in memory allocation and pointers, you should switch to `std::vector<Circle>` instead of using pointers with `new` and `delete`. Manual memory management is error-prone. For example, you got it wrong in your `Collection` destructor above and were leaking memory. Using a standard container like `vector` will take care of memory management for you. A good rule of thumb is to never use `new` and `delete` unless you really have to.

Answer (score 1):

`Collection::getCircleAt` does not return in all cases. This is undefined behaviour and can result in some really bizarre behaviour even if the error is not triggered. A function with a non-`void` return type must return ion every path. This is beaten to death in the comments.

What hasn't been covered is how to fix it.

## Option 1: Throw an exception

```
Circle& Collection::getCircleAt(const Point &p)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)     
        if(circles[i]->contains(p) ) 
          return *(circles)[i];

    throw std::runtime_error("No circle at P")
}
```

This incurs a significant performance penalty if `p` is frequently not associated with a circle. As in it is not exceptional behaviour. You only want to use exceptions for exceptional behaviour. If there should be a `Circle` at `p` and it's a rare and unusual event worth of special reporting when there isn't, us an exception.

```
g.getCircleAt(p).setColor(2);
```

will utterly fail if there is no `Circle`, suggesting this is a good choice here.  You can catch and handle the exception here, leave it for a another function up the call stack to deal with (there aren't any in the asker's example) or let the program crash and harvest the message bundled with the exception to see why. Read your text's section on exception handling for more information.

If no `Circle` at `p` is a regular expected event, exception is probably the wrong tool. Proceed to option 2

## Option 2: Return a canary value

```
Circle* Collection::getCircleAt(const Point &p)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)     
        if(circles[i]->contains(p) ) 
          return (circles)[i];

    return nullptr;
}
```

Note the return type has been changed to a pointer so that it is legal to return a null. Never put yourself  in a position where you are returning a null reference even if the compiler will let you.  Null references are a nasty surprise no one should have to deal with. The pointer at least gives you some warning that a null may come your way, so watch out:

```
g.getCircleAt(p)->setColor(2);
```

Just dereferenced and accessed a null pointer. Kaboom. If the program did not crash, and it doesn't have to, the program just went insane. You need to do more. For example,

```
Circle * c = g.getCircleAt(p)
if (c != nullptr)
{
    c->setColor(2);
}
else
{
    // do error handling
}
```

You the programmer now have to do all of the error handling yourself, but you have total control and you know the costs. If it's not important, keep calm and and carry on. If it needs to be dealt with, deal with it.

## Option 2A: `std::optional`

`optional` formalizes the canary value. You can test it to make sure you got a response and then carry on. First, some documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

`optional` literally just showed up in the C++17 standard revision. I think it was formally ratified in September or October, so it may not be available to you unless you are using the very latest of compilers.

In fact, I do not have such a compiler available and can't provide code that I've tested and know will work at the moment. That's why this is Option 2A. You're on your own with this one. I haven't had a chance to play with it yet.

Comment: The "canary value" option can also be used by returning a reference to a static dummy circle, this allows the caller code to be simpler in many cases